# Do Quranists reject tafsir (explanations of the Qur'an)?

Tags: tafseer, quran-only

> Quranism describes any form of Islam that accepts the Quran as revelation but rejects the religious authority, and/or authenticity of, the Hadith collections. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quranism)

Frequently, non-Quranists use ahadith to better understand the Qur'an.  Likewise, they use tafsir to better understand the Qur'an.

> A Quranic tafsir will often explain content and provide places and times, not contained in Quranic verses, as well as give the different views and opinions of scholars on the verse. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir)

This motivates my question:

**Question**: Do Quranists also reject tafsir?

The Wikipedia page for [Quranism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quranism) also writes:

> Ahle Quran scholars may use Tafsir when pursuing the interpretations of the Quran.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

While an unreferenced snippet, this suggests it's possible that different Quranists have different attitudes towards tafsir.  The Wikipedia page for [tafsir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir) <strike>currently also writes</strike> used to write:

> Wahid Al-Qur'an, or "The Qur'an Alone" (a.k.a. Quranism [قرآنيون Qurʾāniyūn]) is the school of tafsir first used by Muslims during the first two centuries of Islamic history<sup>[Source needed]</sup>.

This indicates that Quranists have a different kind of relationship with tafsir.

Comment: AFAIK they would reject any hadith based tafsir, this means most classical tafsir books there are a few tafsir books that refer to Arabic language and other verses of the Quran which might not fall in this category.

Comment: That's because I deleted it from the Wikipedia page, along with an argumentative section on Quranism which was irrelevant to tafsir.

Comment: sorry even if i had noticed that you edited the text I was not aware that the phrase "used to write" was added!!

Comment: The issue with Quranists is that they seem to hold different positions and one could say different sects, so basically it is hard to answer a question on this topic, because of these differences. As some reject any classical tafsir, while others would only reject hadiths quoted in them others would reject any tafsir by a "non-Quranist" etc. some base their Arabic understanding on orientalist dictionaries and interprete the Quran based on this...

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, Qur'an-only Muslims tend to be diverse; some outright reject anything outside of the Qur'an, while others allow outside material to varying degrees.

[Ahmed Subhi Mansour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmed_Subhy_Mansour), for example, writes (sourced from [here](http://www.ahl-alquran.com/English/show_article.php?main_id=6001)):

> So long as God is sufficient enough for the Believer as a lord, then so too is the Book of God sufficient enough for guidance and legislation ...

In this way, Qur'an-only Muslims may insist on interpreting the Qur'an themselves.  A user of the Qur'an-only [free-minds.org forum](https://free-minds.org/forum/index.php?topic=9598759.10) explains the situation as:

> Some of us might accept the tafsir of Rashad, but not all.  **I think there's more of us that prefers to study by ourselves and develop our own tafsir.**

(While a forum post is not a reliable reference, it's difficult to find authoritative Qur'an-only sources on the topic, and thus this may be the best available source.)

The post is referring to a translation of the Qur'an ([pdf](http://www.quranalone.com/media/quran-english.pdf)) by Qur'an-only proponent [Rashad Khalifa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashad_Khalifa).  In this translation, there are extensive footnotes which can be considered to as tafsir.

A paradox arises in Qur'an-only Islam if tafsir weren't rejected; the Qur'an is simultaneously assumed to be possible to interpret by oneself, while at the same time tafsir is needed in some way.

(This paradox likewise comes up in Salafism; see the paper J. A. C. Brown, *Is Islam Easy to Understand or Not?: Salafis, the Democratization of Interpretation and the Need for the Ulema*, J. Islamic Studies (2015) 26 (2): 117-144 ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1093/jis/etu081)).)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the paradox in Quranists' not rejecting tafsir. But this problem is more extensive: first, Quranists believe in re-interpreting the Quran using the Quran alone as a reference, but these interpretations are themselves tafsir, and vary wildly from person to person. Ahmed Mansour is more well-educated and reasonable, yet he would welcome other opinions and possibly not dismiss them out of hand. The "paradox" may really be a need for leadership and scholarship to rein in the anything goes attitude which undermines faith in basic truths and respect for knowledge.

Comment: On the other hand, allowing for individuals to "interpret for themselves" should not be prohibited provided there are standards for this. Part of the problem for Quranists may be a lack of tafsir that does not use hadeeths as a source in some way or rely on interpretations based on perhaps indirect correlation with hadeeths.They are a relatively small group, and have not developed a set of guidelines based on their own scholars as far as I know. But I do believe the Quranic injunction to use our minds/ have understanding is valid as a guide for both Quranists and "traditional" Muslims.